# AngualrJS delimiter between anchors

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm attempting to take and array of strings and output them as an inline list of html anchors (clickable tags). Here's the code I currently have.

```
<div class="tags">Tags: 
    <a ng-click="searchByTag(tag)" ng-repeat="tag in obj.Tags">
        {{tag}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
    </a>
</div>
```

This works but the comma is included inside the html anchor. How would I go about placing the delimiter outside of the anchor?

**WORKAROUND**

The code below will give the desired layout but requires each anchor to be wrapped in a span. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in obj.Tags">
    <a ng-click="searchByTag(tag)">{{tag}}</a>{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
</span>
```

Comment: You could use css `::before/::after`, so you don't have to clutter the view.

Comment: @Yoshi, thank you. You have led me to an all CSS solution.

`.tags a + a:before { content: ", "; }`

Comment: You could add that as an answer. I'm sure people will find it useful.

Comment: Actually. After looking at my solution it produces the same result. The comma is included inside the anchor tag. So this does not address my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-stop: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<div class="tags">Tags: 
        <a ng-click="searchByTag(tag)" ng-repeat-start="tag in obj.Tags">
            {{tag}}
        </a>
       <span ng-repeat-stop>{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use comment directive.

```
<div class="tags">Tags: 
    <!-- directive: ng-repeat tag in obj.Tags -->
    <a ng-click="searchByTag(tag)">
        {{tag}}
    </a>
    {{$last ? '' : ', '}}
    <!-- /ng-repeat -->
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/tour, as this answer is far too broad. You even get a badge when you read it completely to the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to the party and the OP probably already figured it out, but you can add the delimiter to a `<span>` and set `ng-if` on that `<span>` so that it is hidden if we are on the last element:

```
<div class="tags">Tags: 
  <a ng-click="searchByTag(tag)" ng-repeat-start="tag in obj.Tags">
    {{tag}}
  </a>
  <span ng-repeat-end ng-hide="$last">{{', '}}</span>
</div>
```